# Compare interface to nil

Tags: go

In the Google sheets [example](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/go) there is this piece of code  down the bottom that loops over the rows in a spreadsheet:

```
for _, row := range resp.Values {
  // Print columns A and E, which correspond to indices 0 and 4.
  fmt.Printf("%s, %s\n", row[0], row[4])
}
```

However this code gives an error if there is an empty row in the spreadsheet due to referencing `row[0]` when `row` is an empty interface of size two `<[]interface {}> (length: 0, cap: 0)`

A simple if statement to check if `row` is empty doesn't work as `row == nil` shows `false`.

How can I check if `row` is emmpty?

Comment: `len(row) == 0`

Comment: Or, since you need index 4, better yet use `len(row) < 5`.

Comment: @Adrian oops :(.......write answer and i'll accept. It had crossed my mind but thought it had to be more complicated than that...

Comment: Go aims to have as little as possible that has to be complicated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I check if row is emmpty?

```
if len(row) == 0 { // row is empty
```

But since you need to access index 4 you might as well check for what you actually need:

```
if len(row) < 5 { // row doesn't have an index 4
```